# "Error: could not handle the request" google cloud functions error

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get multiple docs from Firestore using cloud functions. I'm using typescript and trying to push all the docs one by one into an array of objects and then after getting all the docs into an array send it as a response to the client. but I'm getting an error "Error getting documents: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" when trying to run it in the browser.

Here is the code of the function:

```
export const getMultiData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) 
=> {
let dataArray: object[];
const promise = admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("collection")
    .get();
const p = promise.then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      dataArray.push(doc.data());
    });
    response.send(dataArray);
  });
  p.catch(error => {
      response.status(500).send("Error getting documents: " + error);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doc.data` is a method, not a property.  You'll want to call it with parenthesis.

```
dataArray.push(doc.data());
```

Comment: I have edited the question. please check again. I have done some changes to the code and getting a different error now. Now the error is TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: You need to assign an array value to dataArray.  `dataArray = []`

Comment: OK, please accept the answer as correct if you found it helpful.